# Querying selection of values in XML in SQL Server, on table of mixed values

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, apply

I have a table with people who have bought tickets for a charity evening event, and the table contains details of registration event, and the XML will show guests they are bringing with them, but also details of any dietary requirements, and the occasional person who might be disabled. This is supposed to be pushed to our CRM system but this is not currently working.

I'm trying to extract some values out of some XML which is in a column in our import table.

I've seen plenty of examples of querying ordinary chunks of XML, but not when the XML is inside a table with other normal `INT` and `VARCHAR` values.

We are using SQL Server 2014. I've spent hours googling but haven't the faintest idea on making a query that combined the two together. Or even if I'm supposed to push the XML stuff into a temp table which I could then do a join with.

```
Declare @xmlstring xml = '<field_import_admin_event_tickets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <und is_array="true">
    <item>
      <value>8463</value>
      <revision_id>4763</revision_id>
    </item>
  </und>
</field_import_admin_event_tickets>'

select 
    MainDataCenter.Col.value('(value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Name, 
    MainDataCenter.Col.value('(revision_id)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Value
from 
    @xmlstring.nodes('/field_import_admin_event_tickets/und/item') as MainDataCenter(Col)
```

^ this will work

but I need to query it along with this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM [importtickets].[bcc].[entityform]
WHERE type LIKE '%show%'
  AND createdDATETIME > '2019-03-14'
  AND LEN(CAST(field_import_admin_event_tickets AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ) >1
  -- bodging a way of seeing if XML code exists or not, doesn't seem to work with IS NOT NULL
  AND Jobstatus = 'completed'
```

The only way I can crudely get values out of the XML is CAST it to a `VARCHAR` and use lots of REPLACE commands to strip out the XML tags to get it down to the values. There may be 2 to 18 numeric values in each lump of XML

This is my first post on StackOverflow and I've spent days searching on this, so please be gentle with me.   Thanks.

*2019-07-10 Hey, so I didn't make this fully clear.
each column of XML (a few are nulls) contains 2 - 34 separate numbers in.   I dd some crude manipulation of data by CASTing this into VARCHAR and running lots of replace commands to understand it better. 
[this is the largest example here of some XML, 34 integer values, 17 are 'value' and 17 are 'revision_id'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O05o.png)
So I then pushed this all into a new table using lots of SUBSTRING.   This is crude but effective, but assumes each value is five digits long (it is so far)   my boss is not keen on this solution though.
[crudely shredded XML using CAST to VARCHAR and tags manually stripped out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RUMD.png)
I just need each sets of values extracted in each row so I can then do a JOIN or subquery to them, with a row or something identifiable.   The numbers will refer to a guest who is coming to some charity events which will have some attributes such as dietary requirements or disability.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if this is the very best approach for your issue, but I hope that I got your question correctly, that you want to combine the working query against an isolated XML with the tabular query, where the XML is the content of a column:

First of all I create a *mockup* with two rows

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeOtherValue VARCHAR(100),YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable(SomeOtherValue,YourXml) VALUES
('This is some value in row 1'
,'<field_import_admin_event_tickets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <und is_array="true">
    <item>
      <value>8463</value>
      <revision_id>4763</revision_id>
    </item>
  </und>
</field_import_admin_event_tickets>')

,('This is some value in row 2'
,'<field_import_admin_event_tickets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <und is_array="true">
    <item>
      <value>999</value>
      <revision_id>888</revision_id>
    </item>
  </und>
</field_import_admin_event_tickets>');
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.SomeOtherValue
      ,MainDataCenter.Col.value('(value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Name 
      ,MainDataCenter.Col.value('(revision_id)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Value
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('/field_import_admin_event_tickets/und/item') as MainDataCenter(Col);
```

The result

```
ID  SomeOtherValue               Name   Value
1   This is some value in row 1  8463   4763
2   This is some value in row 2   999    888
```

The idea in short:

`APPLY` allows to call a table-valued function row-wise. In this case we hand in the content of a column (in your case the XML) into the built-in function `.nodes()`.
Similar to a `JOIN` we get a joined set, which adds columns (and rows) to the final set. We can use the `.value()` method to retrieve the actual values from the XML.

If this is the best approach? I don't know...

Your sample above shows just one single `<item>`. `.nodes()` would be needed to return several `<item>` elements in a derived set. With just one `<item>` this could be done more easily using `.value()` directly...

Comment: Hi Shnugo,

I really appreciate your help,

But actually I need to extract the values from the XML column so I query them alongside the rest of the table.    Each lump of XML will have 2 - 18 values, half being from "value" and half being "revision_id"

Comment: @bcn_jonathan, Please re-enter your question through the edit option and try to add a [mcve]. You can use my code with the declared test table. Add some reduced but realistic sample data and the expected output. I'm sorry, but your comment does not tell me what issues you have...